# Catching some values in django signals

Tags: django, model, signals

I'm using django signals to catching some values. My example:

```py
@receiver(post_save, sender=Profile)
def my_example(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        user_id = instance.user.id
        level = instance.is_admin
        company = instance.company
```

I need to catch `user_id`, `level` and `company`. But only `user_id` contains value. `company` value is always `None` and `level` is always `False`.

This is my basic model for profile:

```py
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    is_supervisor = models.BooleanField("Supervisor", default=False)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField("Admin", default=False)
    company = models.ForeignKey(
        "core.company",
        related_name="users",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
    )


    def __str__(self):
        """Unicode representation of MyUser."""
        return self.user


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

And a simple test to pass values:

```
def test_example:
    company = Company.objects.create(name="company1")
    user_test = User.objects.create(username="user_test")
    user_test.profile.company = company
    user_test.profile.is_admin = True
    user_test.profile.save()
    user_test.save()
```

And the result:

```
user_id = user_test
company = None
level = False
```

[image: example]

Comment: Since you each time create `Profile.objects.create(user=instance)`, it will indeed by default always take the `default` for these values. Why do you expect it to be different?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Thanx. I'm running some tests and putting the values (True for a level for example). The problem is just the default return. I will update my question with a sample test.

Comment: That's not what's happening: When your code creates a user, this triggers the `create_user_profile` receiver, which creates a profile with only user=user.id. This then triggers your `my_example` signal with `created = True` so you'll always have the default values in here. **All of this** happens on the line `user_test = User.objects.create()`, **before** you assign company and is_admin.

Comment: Maybe you want these values not when the profile is created the first time, but when it's saved, in which case you should either remove `if created` or check for `if not created`.

Comment: @dirkgroten great explanation! Thanks. I set to `if not created` but continues the same values.  I tried like this (with `if not created`): `user = instance.user`(ok, user_test), `company = user.profile.company` (None) and `level = user.profile.is_admin` (False).

Comment: where are you actually looking at the values? your code doesn't show that. You set a breakpoint in your signal receiver and look at the values there?

Comment: @dirkgroten I'm using pycharm's debug (updated my post with image). The purpose of my signal is, when a profile is created, to do something when is_admin or is_supervisor, depending on company too. Therefore I need to catch company and know the user profile (admin or supervisor).

Comment: that's not the same code as in your question, where `company = instance.company`.

Comment: also check in your debugger's stack on which part of the code you are halted. Are you inside the line `user_test.profile.save()` of your `test_example` function?

Comment: @dirkgroten about `company = instance.company` same behavior. The second issue, yes the `user_test.profile.save()`  line.

Comment: that is weird. this shouldn't help (means something else is going on) but try in your main code inside `test_example` method: `profile = user_test.profile; profile.company = company; profile.save()` instead of going via `user_test.profile`. It should cache the `profile` (it's actually a reverse related field) but maybe in your case it refetches it from db each line and the caching doesn't work.

Comment: @dirkgroten Sorry for my lag. Same behavior. For my purpose: automatically take a action when a profile is created, I tried to use User instead Profile. Seems work, but I think this is not a better practice.